# Converting inconsistent strings to date

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with a data set that has a date column in the form of string. I thought it would a simple by doing something like this:

```
to_date(date_of_birth,'YYYY-01-01')
```

date_of_birth is in the format DD/MM/YYYY, and is of type 'text'

HOWEVER, I stumbled upon some crazy cases where you have information like

`//1980`

Another case was:

`0/0/1980`

When I run my solution, I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid value "//19" for "YYYY"
DETAIL:  Value must be an integer.
```

My goal actually is simply to collect the year, since that's at least consistent. How do you handle such cases with Postgres?

EDIT:

Switched it to the following:

```
to_date(date_of_birth,'01/01/YYYY')
```

My query is this:

```
SELECT to_date(date_of_birth,'01/01/YYYY') AS year, COUNT(*) AS yearTotal FROM student WHERE date_of_birth LIKE '%/%/1980' GROUP BY year;
```

The result turns out like this:

`year      | yeartotal 
---------------+-----------
 0030-01-01    |         3
 0001-01-01 BC |         1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem through manipulating the date information (which was of type string) into 'YYYY' in order to access the proper information through date_part.

Using PostgreSQL's "right" function, I was able to collect the year from the string written in the format "DD/MM/YYYY", where right('10/12/2013',4) will return '2013'.

My query looked like this:

```
SELECT date_part('year', to_date(right(date_of_birth,4),'YYYY')) AS year, COUNT(*) AS total FROM student GROUP BY year
```

Another way I could've solved the problem was through regex by ensuring that I only work with 'valid' date statements. Something along the line of (using Python regex as an example):

```
regexp_matches(date_of_birth, '.\/.\/\d{4}')
```

Answer (score -1):

try TO_CHAR instead of TO_DATE, it worked for me

```
SELECT replace(date_of_birth,'//','') AS year, COUNT(*) AS yearTotal FROM student GROUP BY year;
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: 
`ERROR:  function to_char(text, unknown) does not exist`

Comment: It's text, and the format is DD/MM/YYYY. So, for example, Oct 5 1980 would be 05/10/1980.

Comment: ok just check if this query working SELECT Extract(year from date_of_birth) FROM student

Comment: I know that won't wort given that extract is exclusive to either timestamps or ints. The first step that has to happen is to transform text into date. But if there are cases like '//1980', where month and day aren't provided, how would you solve that?

Comment: select replace(date_of_birth , '//' , '' ) FROM  student